# Problem making my ActivityIndicator run when binding IsBusy

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019

On my main page I have an ActivityIndicator running when IsBusy is true, this works fine, but when I use the same configuration on another page it does not run.

IsBusy resides in my BaseViewModel which is then initiated in the ViewModelBase, my code as follows...

```
public class BaseViewModel : BaseSession
{
    //Some other properties .....

    public bool IsConnected
    {
        get { return _IsConnected; }
        set { SetProperty(ref _IsConnected, value); }
    }
    public bool IsBusy
    {
        get { return isBusy; }
        set { SetProperty(ref isBusy, value); }
    }

}
```

ViewModelBase...

```
public class ViewModelBase : BaseViewModel
{
  //Lots of other Properties
}
```

page properties...

```
 class BaseNetWork : ViewModelBase
{
    public BaseNetWork(Grid grid, Image img, Label lbl)
    {
        BaseImages Images = new BaseImages();
        NetworkShares NetWorkData = new NetworkShares();

        img.GestureRecognizers.Add((new TapGestureRecognizer((view) => OpenShares())));
        void OpenShares()
        {

            if (IsConnected)
            {
                grid.Children.Clear();
                img.Source = Images.GetImages(4);
                lbl.Text = "Connect";
                IsConnected = false;

            } else {

                IsBusy = true; // Set the IsBusy to true for the ActivityIndicator.
                NetWorkData.DeploySharesToGrid(grid, null, ConnectToShares);
                IsConnected = true;
                if (IsConnected)
                {
                    img.Source = Images.GetImages(3);
                    lbl.Text = "Disconnect";
                };
                IsBusy = false; // Set the IsBusy back to false.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

View.xaml.cs...

```
    public partial class FolderView : ContentPage
{

    BaseImages Images = new BaseImages();
    BaseNetWork viewModel;

    public FolderView()
    {           
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = viewModel = new BaseNetWork(GridFolders, btnConnect, lblNet);
    }
    void CloseEntries(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (viewModel.IsConnected)
        {
            GridFolders.Children.Clear();
            btnConnect.Source = Images.GetImages(4);
            lblNet.Text = "Connect";
            viewModel.IsConnected = false;
        }
    }
}
```

View.xaml...

```
    <ScrollView>
    <StackLayout Padding="{StaticResource PagePadding}" Spacing="{StaticResource PageSpacing}">
        <Grid RowDefinitions="{StaticResource BrowseShareRows}" ColumnDefinitions="{StaticResource BrowseShareColumns}">
            <Label x:Name="lblNet" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" Text="Connect"/>
            <Image x:Name="btnConnect" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalOptions="Start" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Source="folder_darkblue.png"></Image>
            <StackLayout  Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                <controls:Checkbox x:Name="cbHello" Text="{Binding ViewMessage}" Checked="{Binding ConnectToShares}" PropertyChanged="CloseEntries"/>
            </StackLayout>
            <ScrollView Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="5">
                <StackLayout>
                    <Grid x:Name="GridFolders" Style="{StaticResource FolderStyle}" IsVisible="{Binding AllowViewGrid}"></Grid>
                </StackLayout>
            </ScrollView>
            <ActivityIndicator Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Color="red" IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}"/>
        </Grid>
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

viewthatworks.xaml.cs

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //ConnectivityTest();
        BindingContext = new ViewModelBase();
    }
```

viewthatworks.xaml

```
    <ScrollView>
    <StackLayout Padding="{StaticResource PagePadding}" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Spacing="{StaticResource PageSpacing}">
        <Grid x:Name="controlGrid" RowDefinitions="{StaticResource MainRowStyle}" ColumnDefinitions="{StaticResource MainColumnStyle}" Style="{StaticResource MainGridStyle}">
                <Grid RowDefinitions="{StaticResource GridRowLayout3}" ColumnDefinitions="{StaticResource GridColumnLayout3}" >
                    <Entry x:Name="txtLocation" Text="{Binding GetFolder}"
                        Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"
                        Style="{StaticResource MainEntryStyle}"
                        Placeholder="Name"/>
                    <Button x:Name="btnSave" Text="Save Folder"
                        Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"
                        Style="{StaticResource MainButtonStyle}"
                        IsEnabled="{Binding IsNotBusy}"
                        Command="{Binding SaveContactCommand}"/>
                    <Button x:Name="btnCreate" Text="Create"
                        Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"
                        Style="{StaticResource MainButtonStyle}"
                        IsEnabled="{Binding IsNotBusy}"
                        Command="{Binding CreateDir}"/>
                    <Button x:Name="btnGrid" Text="App"
                        Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="1"
                        Style="{StaticResource MainButtonStyle}"
                        Clicked="Get_Grid"/>
                </Grid>
            </StackLayout>
            <ActivityIndicator IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" Color="red"/>
        </Grid>   
    </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Can anyone please say why the ActivityIndicator is not running?

Comment: you've included a lot of code here, but it's unclear what is what.  Which is the page that works, and which is the page that doesn't work?

Comment: Hi Jason, I have added the page that works, you will see the only difference is that the 'Bindingcontext = new ViewModelBase' is called on the main page, and in the FolderView it uses 'BindingContext = viewModel = new BaseNetWork(GridFolders, btnConnect, lblNet);' Just to be clear, I have tried both ways of approach and it gives the same problem. The only reason I gave the Base object is to show the where the IsBusy derives from.

Comment: I'm guessing the problem is that the UI doesn't have an opportunity to do anything. You set IsBusy to true, then do a bunch of work on the same thread, then set it to false.

Comment: Hi Shawn, Well It's strange, I previously tested it with `await Task.Delay(4000);` and it still didn't do anything, also...it has 10 seconds to fire because it's scanning all network devices with a range up 100 IP's so normally the time is long enough, now all of a sudden it's working :-) so I will close this thread, thank you both for your intervention.

Comment: @Mark Do you solve your issue now? According to your description, I don't see where you implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface to notify IsBusy property changed?

Comment: @Cherry Bu, sorry for the misunderstanding, i didn't place the question as answered, how I did say in my last comment ... "now all of a sudden it's working :-)" , I think maybe I didn't press save after updating some code doh :-) because the object is updated and the page is getting the updated property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the misunderstanding, I didn't place the question as answered, I think maybe I didn't press save after updating some code doh :-) because the object is updated and the page is getting the updated property

Comment: So you have solved your issue now, if yes, please remember to mark your reply as answer, it is beneficial to other community members, thanks.